# Issue while dynamically compiling jSF2 managed bean class (Using java compiler)

Tags: java, jsf-2

i am getting below exception while compiling manually generated managed managed bean java files(JSF2 with annotations),

```
error: Class names, 'javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean,javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped,javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested.
```

Below is my code.

```
    List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();
    options.add("-classpath");
    options.add(servletContextPath + "WEB-INF\\lib");
    options.add("-d");
    options.add(servletContextPath + "WEB-INF\\classes");
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileMan = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null,
            null, null);
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> fileObjs = fileMan
            .getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(javaFileName));
    List<String> annotationClassesToCompile = new ArrayList<String>();
    annotationClassesToCompile.add(ManagedBean.class.getName());
    annotationClassesToCompile.add(SessionScoped.class.getName());
    annotationClassesToCompile.add(ManagedProperty.class.getName());
    CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileMan, diagnostics,
            options, annotationClassesToCompile, fileObjs);*/
    final Boolean result = task.call();
    System.out.println(result.toString() + diagnostics);
    for (Diagnostic diag : diagnostics.getDiagnostics()) {
        System.out.println(diag.getMessage(Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message `error: Class names, 'X', are only accepted if annotation processing is explicitly requested.` is displayed when the extension is incorrect for the supplied class to be compiled. There ought to be a `.java` suffix for all source files that are compiled via the [Java Tools](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/package-summary.html) API.

Although the StandardJavaFileManager API documentation indicates that regular files may be supplied, this appears to be currently restricted to files with the .java extension, arising out of the fix for [bug 6422327 in the Sun Bug DB](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6422327).

Comment: Thanks for replying and we found the solution as well. The soultion is to add the jsf jars path as well to the classpath. List<String> options = new ArrayList<String>();     options.add("-classpath");     options.add(servletContextPath + "WEB-INF\\lib");     options.add("-d");     options.add(servletContextPath + "WEB-INF\\classes");